# Can only print one element from an array in a Text Area, need to print all. Using Netbeans

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, jtextarea

```
private void displayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        for(int j=0; j <= topics.size(); j++)  {
              outputBox.setText("Pg#"+ j + ": " + topics.get(j));
        }
```

This bit of code will only display one element from my array in the text area, any Ideas or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Quick simple answer 1: Use append to append text to text already present in a JTextArea. Quick simple answer 2: Use a StringBuilder to create build your String within your for loop, and then set the JTextArea's text with the so-constructed String. Better long-term answer: work on your search skills since this sort of question is commonly asked and easy to find on this site or via Google, or just by perusing the JTextArea entry in the Java API.

Comment: Note that your for loop looks at risk to throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException due to this expression: `j <= topics.size();`. Are you sure that you want to use `<=` here?

Answer (score -1):

Every single time you call setText() you are replacing the data. You can only do one because you keep over writing it.

You need to add a new line instead.

In order to do this you want to:

```
outputBox.append(yourtext);
outputBox.append('\n'); //when you want to add a new line
```

Comment: Could you possibly be slightly more specific, I understand what you said, It's just that I don't know how to implement the new line...

Comment: @GrandMaster: look at the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870630/java-jtextarea-adding-a-newline) please.

Comment: @GrandMaster: or simply Google [add new line JTextArea](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=add+new+line+to+jtextarea), the top 10 hits all say the same thing.